# Are there any standard exceptions?

Tags: exception, d, standard-library

I've been using `throw new Exception("...")` in my code, since I couldn't find anything else to use.  I'm looking for things like [C++'s](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/stdexcept/) [`out_of_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/stdexcept/out_of_range/) and [`logic_error`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/stdexcept/logic_error/) classes.

[`std.exception`](http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_exception.html) defines a handful of functions to help with *handling* exceptions, but no actual types.

Are we meant to define all our own exceptions, or is `Exception` just used for everything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do Phobos (and/or Tango) have a set of predefined exception types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069066/do-phobos-and-or-tango-have-a-set-of-predefined-exception-types)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the most part in Phobos, each module has its own exception type named after the module - e.g. `UTFException` for std.utf and `FileException` for std.file. There are a few which don't (e.g. std.concurrency has several exception types - `MessageMismatch`, `OwnerTerminated`, etc.), but that's the overall trend. As such, there are no exception types created with the idea that programmers would be instantiating them themselves. There's nothing to stop you from using any of the existing exception types, but in most cases, reusing them doesn't make sense, since they're module-specific rather than use-case specific.

Now, the closest analogy to C++'s `out_of_range` and `logic_error` types would be `Error`s rather than `Exception`s - specifically `core.exception.RangeError` and `core.exception.AssertError`. `Error`s are different and are not intended to be recovered from. core.exception defines several of them (including `OutOfMemoryError`). You wouldn't normally be using those yourself, but you can if you want to. `AssertError` is what is thrown by `assert` when it fails.

So, to be clear, `Throwable` is the base exception type. `Error` and `Exception` are derived from `Throwable`. Any exception type which is not derived from `Exception` skips destructors, scope statements, and finally blocks and is *not* intended to be recovered from. Several standard `Error`s exist - primarily found in core.exception, but you can define your own if you need them. You probably won't use or define `Error`s very often though - aside from using `assert`.

On the other hand, anything derived from `Exception` *is* intended to be recoverable and *will* trigger destructors, scope statements, and finally blocks. There are *not* generally standard `Exception`-derived types that you would instantiate in your own code. You catch the `Exception`s that Phobos defines, but you don't generally throw them. Rather, you either instantiate `Exception` directly or you use your own `Exception`-derived type.

It's also frequently considered good practice to use [`enforce`](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_exception.html#enforce) and [`enforceEx`](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_exception.html#enforceEx) rather than throwing an exception directly (though there are obviously cases where it makes better sense to throw one directly).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation of errors versus exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

[druntime defines a few](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/core_exception.html). There are also specific ones for bad errno and the like in specific modules.